# Is there a anyway to communicate device using php?

Tags: php, device, solution, serial-communication

I would to know, is there any solution or possibility to communicate device like

1. ECG
2. Spirometry
3. ABPM(MAPA)
4. HOLTER...

using php ?

Medical device mapping and identification-Data transfer

I would like identify the device and mapping the device to my web application using php and read the device input and convert the input into binary data file format and convert binary data into view able data.

Is this possible using php ? Or what method should be the solution?

Comment: Easiest way is to send POST data to the php's URL, from the device itself, for this you mainly need to modify the device's software.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no way to communicate with device ID. PHP is a server side language, and it is running only on a server. What is going on client-side,  PHP does not know. 
You can try using JavaScript or best way is to use JAVA for the device control.